# No puedo relacionar cierta tabla

Tags: mysql

Al hacer uso de mi código para relacionar tablas, 3 de las 4 logran relacionarse, mas la 4ta tabla llamada *Proveedores* no se relaciona a pesar  de haber hecho el código varias veces y que su procedimiento fuese satisfactorio, mas aquella 4ta tabla queda en el aire. Adjunto código:

```sql
Create Database Elguesaso3

Create table Facturas (
IDFac int primary key identity(1,1),
Factura varchar(80) not null,
Cliente varchar(80) not null,
Fecha varchar(80) not null,
Modelo varchar(80) not null,
Total varchar(80) not null,
)
go



Create table Proveedores (
IDProv int primary key identity(1,1),
Nombre varchar(80) not null,
Apellido varchar(80) not null,
Direccion varchar(80) not null,
Numero varchar(80) not null,
Descripcion varchar(80) not null
)
go

ALTER TABLE Proveedores
add constraint Fk_vehiculos_proveedores foreign key (IDProv) References Facturas (IDFac),
constraint fk_fac foreign key (IDProv) references Vehiculos (IDVehiculo)

Create table vehiculos (
IDVehiculo int primary key identity(1,1),
Marca varchar(80) not null,
Modelo varchar(80) not null,
Motor varchar(80) not null,
Lanzamiento varchar(80) not null,
Produccion varchar(80) not null,
Precio varchar(80) not null,
Potencia varchar(80) not null,
Cilindrada varchar(80) not null,
Color varchar(80) not null,
IDProveedor varchar(80) not null,
)
go

ALTER TABLE Vehiculos
add constraint Fk_Vehiculos foreign key (IDVehiculo) References Facturas (IDFac),
constraint fk_Proveedores foreign key (IDVehiculo) references Empleados (IDEmp)

Create table Empleados (
IDEmp int primary key identity(1,1),
Cargo varchar(80) not null,
Nombre varchar(80) not null,
Apellido varchar(80) not null,
Cedula varchar(80) not null,
Total varchar(80) not null
)
go
```

Comment: ¿Realmente es MySQL o es SQL Server? Además, ¿da algún error? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: y que error te da?? y el orden de creacion es importante...

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en las definiciones de las claves foráneas en las tablas Proveedores y Vehiculos, ya que estás intentando relacionarlas con la tabla Facturas, pero en la creación de la tabla Facturas, no hay ninguna columna con el nombre IDProv. Además, no has creado la tabla Vehiculos antes de intentar referenciarla en la definición de la tabla Proveedores.

Deberia quedar asi:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE Elguesaso3;

USE Elguesaso3;

CREATE TABLE Facturas (
    IDFac INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Factura VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Cliente VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Fecha VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Total VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Proveedores (
    IDProv INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Apellido VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Direccion VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Numero VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Descripcion VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE Vehiculos (
    IDVehiculo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Marca VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Modelo VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Motor VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Lanzamiento VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Produccion VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Precio VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Potencia VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Cilindrada VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Color VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    IDProveedor INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Vehiculos FOREIGN KEY (IDVehiculo) REFERENCES Facturas (IDFac),
    CONSTRAINT Fk_Proveedores FOREIGN KEY (IDProveedor) REFERENCES Proveedores (IDProv)
);

CREATE TABLE Empleados (
    IDEmp INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Cargo VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Apellido VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Cedula VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    Total VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);
```

Aqui la comprobación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]